# Tapping into the external tankless water heater for outdoor shower

Tags: plumbing

I have an external tankless water heater on the back wall of my home. 20 feet directly to the left is where we want to put our outdoor shower. We currently also have a cold water spigot in the same area. My original plan was to put a hot water spigot next to the cold water spigot and then just run some washing machine hoses over to the outdoor shower. Instead of having to crawl under the house and drill through the band joist to install the spigot I was wondering if it was okay to just put a T in the hot water output of the water heater. Then I could put a ball valve on it and run a hose off of it.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming since the tankless heater itself is outside that you’re someplace without a freeze season.

Comment: @Tyson Not necessarily. Outdoor tankless units just avoid ventilation and exhaust issues. You can find them in a variety of climates, though. That said, if the OP's trying to set up an outdoor shower...

Comment: Correct. I am in Charleston, SC. We had a day or two this winter where the pex at the outdoor water heater froze up, but that was about it.

Comment: Also, what is your concern with this plan? As long as you're downstream of the service valves (and P&T relief valve) then it doesn't seem like an issue.

Comment: @HariGanti I don't have any concern, I'm just looking to see if there are any cons to this approach.

Comment: Well I wouldn't really recommend the hose. It's a little janky... Why not run downward and bury that section? That the only real downside I can foresee (based on the info I have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is fine. ( code issues aside )

If you do not want to drill new holes in the side of your house then I would suggest to not use your hose bib.

If you are going to be plumbing a new line anyway you might as well plumb the cold as well and save your hose bib for alternative uses. Presumably you have an accessible cold water supply to the water heater and plenty of water pressure, T off the cold going into the WH for the cold and T into the hot coming out of the WH. Run both lines ( copper or pex ) to a shower mixing valve, put 1/4 turn valves in line so you can service/shut it off.

I would build some sort of cover/housing to put over the supply lines to the mixing valve to protect them and for aesthetics.

As to freezing. Keep in mind the planet will (more then likely) experience another ice age. South Carolina will freeze/thaw many time before a full ice age ensues but humans will probably be long gone. ( Either through self destruction or leaving this planet to find another planet to  ---abuse for profit?  . )

The planet will survive long after any parasites render their host uninhabitable.  ( alter its climate to the point of not being able to support the life that has evolved to exist within its specific climate parameters. )

But I digress.

I think you should ( PROBABLY ) be good for the near future.

Comment: Great point about the cold water. I’ll go to Lowe’s and do it all now. Thanks!!

Comment: I agree that given the last 20 years, and all that stuff scientists in every country but ours are saying, it's unwise to bet any expensive infrastructure on the notion that climate *won't* change.

Comment: The scientists in the US are saying the same thing as the scientists in other countries; its a certain segment of the US *politicians* that are the dissenters.